# CDF is not starting from zero

Tags: r, cdf

I have a data without any infinite value like below:

```
data<-c(6.87, 0.11, 0, 0.03, 0.08, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.13, 0.17, 0, 0.53, 
0.01, 2.69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.44, 4.71, 3.57, 0.38, 0.31, 0.45, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.09, 0.43, 0, 0.23, 2.31, 0, 
0.01, 0.96, 1.28, 0.07, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.07, 0, 0, 0.03, 5.99, 0.08, 
6.23, 2.95, 0.04, 0, 0.98, 0.03, 17.2, 0, 0, 0.25, 1.99, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 1.94, 1.06, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.02, 0, 0.02, 0.05, 0.66, 0.57, 0.54, 0, 0.11, 0.75, 0.65, 
0, 7.35, 0.22, 0, 1.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.78, 0.28, 0.06, 
0.09, 0.03, 0.01, 0.14, 0.02, 0, 1.82, 0.04, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 
9.52, 10.38, 29.09, 0.1, 0.4, 0, 0.97, 0.57, 0.33, 0.16, 40.19, 
1.06, 5.02, 0.01, 0.79, 4.78, 0.44, 15.29, 7.26, 0.05, 0.01, 
6.47, 37.66, 0, 0.4, 0.15, 1.42, 0, 0.07, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.01, 7.43, 
0, 0.03, 0.02, 0.15, 0.09, 0.44, 1.45, 0.03, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.09, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.04, 
1.52, 0.01, 0, 0.27, 0.01, 1.11, 2.41, 0, 0, 0.15, 0, 0, 1.28, 
0.02, 0.16, 0.17, 1.74, 3.75, 0.05, 0.18, 0.07, 0.39, 0, 0, 0, 
0.45, 0.78, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.09, 
0.17, 0, 0.27, 0.04, 0.02, 0.88, 1.23, 0.01, 0.01, 0.13, 0.6, 
0.02, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.12, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 
0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 2.71, 0.49, 0, 0, 0, 0.84, 
0.04, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.06, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.15, 0, 0.48, 5.34, 5.23, 
0.22, 2.37, 1.55, 3.29, 0, 0, 0.08, 0.03, 0.05, 0.06, 7.62, 0.84, 
0.48, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0.02, 0.08, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.11, 0.1, 0, 0.01, 0, 0.24, 0, 2.4, 1.57, 0.12, 0.03, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.08, 0.56, 0, 0.09, 0.01, 0.09, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0.38, 0.01, 0.03, 
0.14, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.08, 0, 6.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.31, 
0.01, 0.03, 0.2, 0.03, 0.02, 0.08, 0.12, 0, 5.79, 0.91, 0.95, 
0, 0.39, 1.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0.64, 0.02, 0, 1.14, 0.24, 
0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 1.28, 0, 0.01, 0.02, 2.18, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.19, 3.9, 0.01, 0.03, 0, 5.93, 0.88, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.07, 0, 4.06, 0.41, 0.04, 0, 0, 0.08, 2.21, 0.03, 0, 8.07, 
0, 0, 0.66, 1.73, 0.17, 0.02, 1.37, 4.68, 0.26, 0.09, 0.2, 0.03, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2.74, 0.1, 0.42, 0.65, 0.53, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 
0.16, 0.17, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.09, 0.01, 0, 0, 
0.69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.13, 0.54, 0, 0.16, 1.57, 
0.12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 0.18, 0, 0.86, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0.37, 0.18, 0, 0, 0, 0.08, 5.25, 1.1, 
0.68, 0.14, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.95, 0.28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.78, 
3.05, 0.39, 1.65, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.25, 0.78, 0, 0, 0, 0.85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.34, 0.45, 0, 
0, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7, 
0.69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 2.01, 0.05, 0, 0.77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.01, 0.79, 0.01, 0, 0.97, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.47, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0.13, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.33, 
0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0.01, 12.31, 7.54, 0, 0, 
0, 0.05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 1.02, 0, 
0, 0.54, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.01, 0.08, 0.03, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.11, 0.25, 0.03, 0, 0, 0.09, 0, 0, 0.01, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 1.41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

When I try to plot CDF, curve is not starting from zero. It starts with 0.57. I read that infinite and zero values can cause this problem. To overcome this I replaced zeros with very small values.

```
data[data==0]<-0.000001
plot(ecdf(data), xlim = c(min(data),max(data)))
```

[image]

But still I am getting same result. Why is that happening?

Comment: The answer to your actual question "Why is that happening?" is because that is the correct and expected behaviour.  The minimum value in your data (zero) has a relative frequency of 0.57.

Comment: It is happening since the most frequent value of your data is the same value with the minimum value of your data. Run `length(data[data==0]) / length(data)`. It gives 0.5794045 which means that possibility of the taking 0 from a random choice is 0.5794045 . You may add a symbolic negative value to your data set to create a low frequency for plotting purpose.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo, since the question seems to be motivated by a misunderstanding about what the ecdf function should do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it makes much sense to show empirical cdf for values outside of observed data. All values that are lower than the minimum of `data` will have ecdf of zero. You could try something like:

```
f = ecdf(data)
curve(f, min(data) - 0.01, max(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

Like it is said in comments to the question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67827014/cdf-is-not-starting-from-zero/67827535#comment119887784_67827014) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67827014/cdf-is-not-starting-from-zero/67827535#comment119887790_67827014), there are many zeros in your data, representing 57% of the total data points.

```
mean(data == 0)
#[1] 0.5794045
```

If you plot the ECDF and an horizontal line at that ordinate, you will see that the ECDF starts there.

```
plot(ecdf(data))
abline(h = mean(data == 0))
```